# CAST(somenumber as VARCHAR(10)) + somestring returns Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql

I'm trying to combine a min and max salary with a hyphen for display in a report. I feel like I've done this a hundred times but I still can't figure out why I'm getting the "Error converting data type varchar to numeric" especially since I'm trying to convert a numeric to varchar not the other way around.

```
amt_exp_formatted = CASE
                       WHEN a.class_code IN ('9997','9998','9999') THEN 0 
                       --ELSE CAST(e.min_sal as VARCHAR(10)) + '-' + CAST(e.max_sal as VARCHAR(10))                             
                         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(1), 1) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(1), 'a')
                    END
```

In the above example if I use 'a' I get the error. If I change 'a' to '9' then it works AND it appends 9 to the 1 (i.e. 19) rather than adding them together which is exactly what I want but with a character string. I've tried both CAST and CONVERT with no luck. I know I shouldn't need the second CONVERT on the letter 'a' but I was just trying to force the data types to be the same just in case. I have no doubt at all I'm missing something simple but I can't seem to get it so I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask the community.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `case` expression returns one value with a *determinate* type.  If any returned fork returns a number, then number it is.  And strings get converted.

So, be sure you are returning a string in all cases:

```
(CASE WHEN a.class_code IN ('9997', '9998', '9999')
      THEN '0' 
      ELSE CONCAT(e.min_sal, '-', e.max_sal)  
 END)
```

`CONCAT()` automatically converts the arguments to strings.

Comment: Dropping single quotes around the 0 worked immediately so thank you! I tried googling determinate, determinate type and determinate type coding and all I get is a bunch of stuff on tomato generics but let me see if I can understand. You are saying if one of the WHEN (or ELSE) lines returns a value with a "number datatype" then every other WHEN (or ELSE) line will be converted to that same  "number type" if returned. Yes?

Comment: @GunnerFan420 . . . Look up type precedence in the documentation for whatever database you are using.

Comment: Well I'll just assume my understanding is correct... thanks to you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is becuase you are mixing the data type. in the first part of case you were returning 0 while in the else part you're converting it to varchar(). - you can try the below returning 0 as also varchar

```
amt_exp_formatted = CASE
                       WHEN a.class_code IN ('9997','9998','9999') THEN '0' 
                       --ELSE CAST(e.min_sal as VARCHAR(10)) + '-' + CAST(e.max_sal as VARCHAR(10))                             
                         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(1), 1) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(1), 'a')
                    END
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply and yes that worked perfectly for me. Thank you sir!